# Help me with my regexp

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match filenames that look like this:

```
45.pdf
```

Or

```
45_2.pdf
```

So there is a positive integer, an optional underscore followed by another positive integer, a full stop and a string reperesenting an extension.

The problem is, my regexp is also matching 45_.pdf which I don't want to.

Here it is:

```
$aRegexp = '/[0-9]+_?[0-9]*\\.[a-z]+/';

//$aString = '55.pdf';
//$aString = '55_5.pdf';
$aString = '55_.pdf';

var_dump(preg_match($aRegexp, $aString)); // should return int(0)
```

Comment: @Close voter: you might as well go and close every other non-general question as too localized while you're at it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Group the underscore and the second integer together, use `+` instead of `*` for the second integer to force a match, and optional-match the entire group with `?`, like so:

```
$aRegexp = '/[0-9]+(_[0-9]+)?\\.[a-z]+/';
```

Comment: Optionally, make it a non-capture group `(?:_[0-9]+)?`.

Comment: I tried to parse by that regex, but it fails to parse "55_5.pdf"? Code: http://codepad.org/EYiT4M2h

Comment: @Hoàng Long: The regex works, codepad's PHP build is broken. The warning you see there indicates a problem in the regex engine for its PHP build, and not the regex.